# Sending “Account is created” mail to the user after creating the account

Tags: email, openam, confirmation, user-registration

I am looking for sending account created email to the user after he creates the account. I have enabled self service and user can create his account, I need to send the email to user once he successfully creates the account with openam. This is not email verification, if we enable email verification then the account is created after verifying the email. I just need to send “fyi your account is created” mail to the user after creating the account. is it possible by out of the box? How? Can we write custom module for this? if we can write custom module for this then please help with details.

Thanks
Deepak!